# is there a way to get the Device Locale from AWS - Device Farm ? I'm currently using Appium-Python-Android

Tags: amazon-web-services, appium, python-appium, aws-device-farm

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the device locale from AWS Device Farm.

I've tried reading the log cat, but the locale set once, so i could only read this info in one test.

I also tried using the driver shell command but in order to do so i need to start the Appium server with --relaxed-security flag and i don't know if passing flags to AWS-Device Farm Appium server is possible.

So, is there a way to get the locale ? or can i set flags to the AWS-Device Farm Appium Server?

Answer (score 0):

The global locale on the device can be retrieved using :

`defaultLocale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);`

Alternatively, you can also use class Locale:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale

`Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()`

Note: There is a difference between the app locale and global locale on the device so you want to be careful on which one you want to use.

Comment: Im talking from a Automation perfective where the only way you have to access the "Android Device" is the AppiumDriver

Comment: May be one way could be to run an adb command from your Appium test code  like:  -
adb shell getprop | grep language
[persist.sys.language]: [en]
[ro.product.locale.language]: [en]